# How to distribute non-jar files to yarn nodes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to distribute `*.tar.gz` file to yarn nodes under APPLICATION level visibility.

On my hadoop node following directory is generated by Node Manager

```
/tmp/hadoop-vikram/nm-local-dir/usercache/vikram/appcache/application_1490062699498_0005/container_1490062699498_0005_01_000003/
```

I do see expected file under

```
/tmp/hadoop-vikram/nm-local-dir/usercache/vikram/appcache/application_1490062699498_0005/filecache/10/test.tar.gz
```

But I would like to retrieve the path to `test.tar.gz` in application code.

I can find paths to jar files using following

```
URL input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jar-file-name");
```

Comment: ¿Why do not you save this tar in a nfs?

Comment: @jedijs I would like to leverage on file distribution performed by Yarn

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing the right thing relying on the container location. For minor collections I recommend you to use [distributed cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to make resource available on all the task nodes. It will automatically upload the file to all container nodes and make it available for all mappers-reducers.

But if your file is big enough this should be a great space hit as data will be copied to every node where the actual task will be performed. To improve this you can put your file directly into your file system with some bigger replication factor, 10 for example (depends on the number of nodes in the cluster), in order to increase its availability. Then in your task you will be able to download it directly which will significantly save your space comparing to the Distributed cache approach, but the cost would be your bandwidth in non-local reads. You can play around with this to find the optimal number of replications.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. My file is not big in size but rather in few 100 kbs. We are already distributing files to container node using LocalResource implementation. But somehow on some of the container this file goes missing .

Comment: @user3401493 Probably you are missing something there. This is the correct way to go, I advice you to try find out the reason of the problem with LocalResource instead of accessing containers directly